# I am unable to obtain access token using OAUTH 2.0 SAML Assertion Bearer flow in python

Tags: python-3.x, oauth-2.0, salesforce, saml-2.0

I am trying to create a SAML Assertion and then post it to the salesforce 
oauth endpoint to obtain the access token in response in my office sandbox environment.

The below code is based on the code mentioned in this repository: https://github.com/salesforceidentity/apex-saml-bearer- flow/blob/master/SAMLBearerAssertion.apex.txt I have tried to convert 
the code into python.

```
import datetime
import random
import hashlib
import binascii
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_v1_5
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode,urlsafe_b64decode,urlsafe_b64encode
import requests
from xml.etree import ElementTree

class SFSAMLAssertion:

def __init__(self, subject, issuer, audience, action):

    self.subject = subject
    self.issuer = issuer
    self.action = action
    self.audience = audience
    self.not_before = "2019-08-16T06:35:13.654Z"
    self.not_on_or_after = "2024-08-14T06:35:13.654Z"
    self.assertion_id = self.create_assertion_id()
    self.encoded_key = ""
    self.preCannonicalizedResponse = """<saml:Assertion xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="ASSERTION_ID" IssueInstant="NOT_BEFORE" Version="2.0"><saml:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">ISSUER</saml:Issuer><saml:Subject><saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">SUBJECT</saml:NameID><saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer"><saml:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="NOT_ON_OR_AFTER" Recipient="RECIPIENT"></saml:SubjectConfirmationData></saml:SubjectConfirmation></saml:Subject><saml:Conditions NotBefore="NOT_BEFORE" NotOnOrAfter="NOT_ON_OR_AFTER"><saml:AudienceRestriction><saml:Audience>AUDIENCE</saml:Audience></saml:AudienceRestriction></saml:Conditions><saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="NOT_BEFORE"><saml:AuthnContext><saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:unspecified</saml:AuthnContextClassRef></saml:AuthnContext></saml:AuthnStatement></saml:Assertion>"""
    self.preCannonicalizedSignedInfo = """<ds:SignedInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></ds:CanonicalizationMethod><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"></ds:SignatureMethod><ds:Reference URI="#ASSERTION_ID"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"></ds:Transform><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></ds:DigestMethod><ds:DigestValue>DIGEST</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo>"""
    self.signatureBlock = """<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">SIGNED_INFO<ds:SignatureValue>SIGNATURE_VALUE</ds:SignatureValue></ds:Signature><saml:Subject>"""

def create_assertion_id(self):
    num = random.randint(1, 999999)
    hash = hashlib.sha256()
    hash.update(bytes(num))
    digest = hash.digest()

    return binascii.hexlify(digest).decode('UTF-8')

def sign_signedinfo(self, data):
    f = open('../etc/privateKey.pem', 'rb')

    key = b64decode(self.encoded_key)
    rsakey = RSA.importKey(f.read())
    signer = PKCS1_v1_5.new(rsakey)
    digest = SHA256.new()
    digest.update(b64encode(data))
    sign = signer.sign(digest)
    return b64encode(sign)

def create_assertion(self):

    self.preCannonicalizedResponse = self.preCannonicalizedResponse.replace('ASSERTION_ID',self.assertion_id)
    self.preCannonicalizedResponse = self.preCannonicalizedResponse.replace('ISSUER', self.issuer)
    self.preCannonicalizedResponse = self.preCannonicalizedResponse.replace('AUDIENCE', self.audience)
    self.preCannonicalizedResponse = self.preCannonicalizedResponse.replace('RECIPIENT', self.action)
    self.preCannonicalizedResponse = self.preCannonicalizedResponse.replace('SUBJECT', self.subject)
    self.preCannonicalizedResponse = self.preCannonicalizedResponse.replace('NOT_BEFORE', self.not_before)
    self.preCannonicalizedResponse = self.preCannonicalizedResponse.replace('NOT_ON_OR_AFTER', self.not_on_or_after)

    # Prepare the digest
    m = hashlib.sha256()
    m.update(bytes(self.preCannonicalizedResponse, encoding='UTF-8'))
    digest = b64encode(m.digest())

    self.preCannonicalizedSignedInfo = self.preCannonicalizedSignedInfo.replace('ASSERTION_ID',self.assertion_id)
    self.preCannonicalizedSignedInfo = self.preCannonicalizedSignedInfo.replace('DIGEST',digest.decode('UTF-8'))

    # Prepare the signedinfo
    input = bytes(self.preCannonicalizedSignedInfo,encoding='UTF-8')

    signature = self.sign_signedinfo(input)
    signature = b64encode(signature)

    # Prepare the signature block
    self.signatureBlock = self.signatureBlock.replace('SIGNED_INFO',self.preCannonicalizedSignedInfo)
    self.signatureBlock = self.signatureBlock.replace('SIGNATURE_VALUE',signature.decode('UTF-8'))

    self.preCannonicalizedResponse = self.preCannonicalizedResponse.replace('<saml:Subject>',self.signatureBlock)

    return self.preCannonicalizedResponse

def get_base64urlencode_string(self):

    data = self.create_assertion()
    data = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>' + data
    print("Assertion: "+data)
    tree = ElementTree.ElementTree(ElementTree.fromstring(data))
    root = tree.getroot()
    output = urlsafe_b64encode(bytes(ElementTree.tostring(root, encoding='UTF-8',method = 'xml').decode(encoding='UTF-8'),encoding='UTF-8'))
    return output

def postSAML(self):

    url = "https://<sandbox_domain>.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token"
    assertion = self.get_base64urlencode_string()
    print(assertion.decode('UTF-8'))
    headers = {
        "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }

    params = {
        "grant-type" : "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:saml2-bearer",
        "assertion" : assertion.decode('UTF-8')
    }

    r = requests.post(url,params=params,headers=headers)
    print(r.status_code)
    print(r.content)
    print(r.headers)
    print(r.url)
```

Currently I am getting an error as "invalid assertion" using my python code. What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

The code you copied from [SAMLBearerAssertion.apex](https://github.com/salesforceidentity/apex-saml-bearer-flow/blob/master/SAMLBearerAssertion.apex.txt) uses SHA-1 for message digest and RSA-SHA1 for signature whereas your code has SHA-256/RSA-SHA256. Change the relevant XML fragments to this:

```
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"></ds:DigestMethod>

<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"></ds:SignatureMethod>
```

For other values of `Algorithm`, see IANA assignments [cheatsheet](https://www.iana.org/assignments/xml-security-uris/xml-security-uris.xhtml).

Comment: I tried making the above mentioned changes, but still I am getting the same "invalid assertion" error. I also tried constructing the exact SAML assertion mentioned at : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_SAML_bearer_flow.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null but still getting the same error.

Comment: There could be lots of reasons why your assertion is rejected, yes. We recommend switching to [JWT Bearer](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&language=en_us&type=5) flow.